# Oracle BI Publisher Java APIs convert Chinese characters to question marks (?)

Tags: java, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I've BI publisher Desktop installed that helps us to generate and visualize PDF from RTF file with sample data. RTF file which we are using is a mix of English and Chinese characters and with sample XML data , we are able to see PDF as we want.

[image: As Expected PDF]
When we use the same RTF in our java code (using BI publisher Java APIs) to create PDF , all the Chinese characters get replaced with question marks (?).

[image: Resultant PDF]

Below is the code where we are converting RTF to PDF

```
        RTFProcessor rtfp = new RTFProcessor(pTemplate);
        ByteArrayOutputStream xslOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rtfp.setOutput(xslOutStream);
        
        rtfp.process();

        //Use XSL Template and Data from the VO to generate report and return the OutputStream of report
        ByteArrayInputStream xslInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xslOutStream.toByteArray());

        FOProcessor processor = new FOProcessor();
        ByteArrayInputStream dataStream =
            new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])pXmlOut); ///amDpc.getXMLData(pVoInstName));
        processor.setData(dataStream);
        processor.setTemplate(xslInStream);
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        processor.setOutput(pdfOutStream);
        byte outFileTypeByte = FOProcessor.FORMAT_PDF;
        
        processor.setOutputFormat(outFileTypeByte); 
        processor.generate();

        dataBytes = pdfOutStream.toByteArray();
```

Googling suggests adding font file to BI publisher $oracle_top location or in $java_home/jre/lib/fonts locations. Since BI publisher is not directly used , option 1 ($oracle_top) is ruled out and Option 2 would require testing of all ADF applications deployed on PROD servers , which I would like to avoid .

Any suggestions on how to print Chinese characters ?

SW Version : Oracle BI Publisher Desktop 12.2.1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved by placing fonts under  $java_home/jre/lib/fonts location.No server bounce was needed.